# Error "Cannot resolve symbol R" only in one file

Tags: java, android, android-viewbinding

When enabling View binding, I cannot reference the resource files in custom RecyclerView Adapter anymore. I get an error "cannot resolve symbol R" and it attempts to automatically import R, which is wrong. This doesn't happen in the Activity, anyway.
(I've already tried checking all xml files, cleaning and rebuilding the project.)

Why is this happening?

**Screenshot of Activity (everything is fine):**

[image: Screenshot of Activity (everything is fine)]

**The custom adapter - can't resolve symbol R:**
[image: The custom adapter - can't resolve symbol R]

**Edit:**

What I don't understand is why there is no such error when I create a project without View binding? Below is an example of a custom adapter in another test app, where no problems with R are seen:

[image: no problems with R]

The question is, in which cases is it required to import a package.R?
Why isn't it always needed and how do I know that everything is correct when suddenly R doesn't get resolved in a particular file and Android Studio attempts to import the package.R?

Comment: So, why do we think that this error "is wrong." exactly?

Comment: I've encountered information many times that you should not import R. For example, [this article](https://medium.com/@nitinkumargove/how-to-resolve-r-cannot-be-resolved-error-in-android-5729970e6fba) states: "Eclipse sometimes likes to add an “import android.R” statement at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask Eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete them."

Comment: And the error doesn't appear when I don't use View binding. Plus in the Activity the error doesn't arise even with View binding. I don't understand that

Comment: you need to import `R` for your specific project. The article says that you should avoid importing `android.R`, so as long as you don't import that you should be able to do something like `import <your.project.path>.R`

Comment: @user3170251 "you need to import R for your specific project" In fact, it's the first time I encounter this. Please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out that the error with R resolving begins when the Java file is located in a subfolder of the package (for example, the ui folder).
Then Android Studio starts to import `package.R`.

For example, in this case:

```
package com.example.test3;
```

there is no R error. But in this one:

```
package com.example.test3.ui;
```

R is not resolved and gets autoimported.

Maybe this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you!! I as well have tried to clean the project, XML file, change gradle version... But somehow this is the only one that actually worked!! Thank you once again!